# automate deployment after making changes on fuse project

Tags: maven, jbossfuse, fuseesb, fabric8

I'm using jBoss Fuse 
I created a fuse project on windows (as a machine for developement) and I deployed it by fabric8 on a linux machine (Centos) as a server (it's running right now) if followed these steps to deploy it:

1. I copied the project from the windows machine to linux machine
2. I did a `maven install`
3. I did maven `fabric8 deploy`, it generated a profile
4. I assigned that profile to a child container i created before

My question is: when I make changes on the application on windows and I want to apply these changes to the deployed app on the server, what should I do ? knowing that I don't want to stop the deployed app?
Is there any other way to deploy the application directly from the windows to a remote server (Centos on my case)
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can edit your pom.xml adding the following configuration

```
<distributionManagement>
 <repository>
    <id>fabric8.vm</id>
    <name>Fabric Maven</name>
    <url>http://<vm ip>:<port, default 8181>/maven/upload</url>
  </repository>
</distributionManagement>
```

Then you can use the command for deploy into your VM

```
mvn clean deploy
```

If your VM network settings is of type "NAT", you have to do a port forward from your host machine to the vm (virtual box -> settings -> network tab -> port forward then create a new rule IP host: 127.0.0.1, host port: 9000, guest IP 10.0.2.15 guest port: 8181) then you can use the url      `<url>http://localhost:9000/maven/upload</url>`

Comment: Thanks for the answer i'll try this tomorrow

Comment: **EDIT** : it works , just a litlle thing to add to `<url></url>` we have to insert the **username** and the **password** on the url to become `<url>http://username:password@localhost:8181/maven/upload</url>` eg `<url>http://admin:admin@192.168.3.107:8181/maven/upload</url>`